# How to show total number in same coordinate in R Programming

Tags: r, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, k-means, visualize

(update 11/09/2017 question)

this is my codes to cluster kmodes in R:

```
library(klaR)
setwd("D:/kmodes")
data.to.cluster <- read.csv('kmodes.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ';')
cluster.results <- kmodes(data.to.cluster[,2:5], 3, iter.max = 10, weighted = FALSE)
  plot(data.to.cluster[,2:5],col= cluster.results$cluster)
```

the result is like this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lzLX.jpg

My sample data : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Z58iD3By5wUzduOXUwUDh1OVU/view

Is there a way to show total number in same coordinate? I mean when clustering if there are many value which is same as 1,1 (x,y) could we make r show the total number in 1,1?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, could you please use output of  `dput(data.to.cluster)` to edit your post for inline data set.

Comment: How do you visualize your input data *prior* to clustering? Don't expect clustering to make visualization easier.

Comment: Also, please don't repost a question. Edit it, to improve your question.

Comment: what's dput(data.to.cluster?

Comment: ah sorry im new to stack overflow i will edit it from now